# Tricky ODE with an Interesting Presentation Coming from P-Laplace on Schwarzchild Space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, analytic-geometry

I am currently looking at the following ODE:
$$2 \frac{y''}{y'}=\frac{\frac{-4}{r}y'-2(p-2)\frac{m}{r^2}(1+\frac{m}{2r})^3}{y'+(p-2)(1+\frac{m}{2r})^4}$$
Does anybody have any examples of standard ODE methods I should be paying particular attention to? I tried to use a perturbation series (letting $p=2+\epsilon$ since we are perturbing away from the standard 2-laplace solution), but I have not had luck getting it into a nice form. The independent variable is r, a radial coordinate, and m,p are constants.

Comment: What is the independent variable here? Is it $r$?

Comment: Yes, the independent variable is r. 'm' and 'p' are constants.

Comment: You can immediately integrate once by substituting $z=y',$ since there is no $y.$ No idea after that, other than numerical integration.

Comment: You can rewrite your equation as an Abel equation of the second kind with respect to $y'$.